# Where in the project code are groups instances created and permissions assigned?

Tags: django, django-permissions

I was going through the documentation of django 2.1, I see that group permissions can be created inside a user model, or directly and then they can be assigned to a group instance using the `permissions` attribute. What I don't get is where in my project should I add the code which creates a `Group` instance and assigns a permission to that instance.

Comment: You mean *programatically*? Or in the admin panel?

Comment: programatically

Answer (score 0):

A [**`Group`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#group-model) is just another model, stored in `django.contrib.auth.models`. We can create a `Group` with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

g1 = Group.objects.create(name='some_group_name')
```

Next we can add [**`Permission`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/#permission-model) objects to it, for example by searching by `codename`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission

p1 = Permission.objects.get(codename='can_add_post')
p2 = Permission.objects.get(codename='can_add_blog')
g1.permissions.add(p1, p2)
```

If you use Django's standard user model, we can also add [**`User`s** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model) to a group:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

u1 = User.objects.get(username='foobar')
g1.user_set.add(u1)
```

Comment: I understand the code, I am just confused as to where this code will be placed so that it runs as soon as it the app is built.

Comment: @Shashwat: you can set it in the `ready()` method of the `AppConfig`, or perhaps in a migration, since this probably should only be done once.